# Can i use 1 fuse for all the outputs to protect my power source from overcurrent?

Tags: fuses, circuit-protection

Can i use 1 fuse for all the outputs to protect my power source from overcurrent by connecting the fuse to the ground wire? I have 3 outputs: 3.3V, 5V, 12V and i want to protect my power source when it reaches more than 10Amps. I don't want to put a fuse for each output. Can i put 1 fuse to the ground connection, where all the ground cables from the outputs go, to protect my circuit?

Here is a simple schematic of what i say:
[image]

Comment: Fusing the ground line sounds like it could be dangerous. The ground connection is often distributed and redundant, through metal cabinets, signal cables and all sorts of other things.

Comment: I downvoted here because this question lacks basic own consideration – just drawing the power supply scheme and adding the fuse where you propose to have would be sufficient to understand why this is a bad idea.

Comment: @MarcusMüller i edited it

Comment: and now add two loads to it, maybe from 12V to ground and from 3.3.V to ground. And then imagine the fuse gets blown. and then watch the current flow. Calculate the current that still flows after.

Comment: @MarcusMüller i got what you are saying. I think i should ad a fuse for each output

Comment: You should not neglect the power input terminals in your diagram since that can matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could, but think about what happens when the fuse blows — you now have some parts of your circuit connected between +3.3V and +5.0V, some connected between +5.0V and 12.0V, and still others connected between +3.3V and +12.0V.

Doesn't sound like anything is "protected", does it?

Comment: What do you mean? When the fuse blows, current won't be able to pass through and all of the outputs won't give any power

Comment: Current can still flow into the 12V terminal powering one device, through the connections and  and out of the 5V powering another device into the 5V supply if ground is not present. In a sewer system, what happens when the main line clogs? Water can flow down one drain and back up another drain. Same idea.

Comment: Post a block diagram of how your power supply inputs and outputs are connected and we will tell you.

Comment: @ΣτελιοςΛιακοπουλος If you only have one fuse on the ground side then it must be true that the grounds of all parts of your circuit will be connected together and will remain connected when the fuse blows. Current will flow from a high supply voltage, through the common ground connection, and then **in reverse** toward a lower voltage supply.

Answer (score 3):

> Can i put 1 fuse to the ground connection, where all the ground cables from the outputs go, to protect my circuit?

No.
A fuse there will not provide protection in most cases, may cause damage in some cases and will be unable to be dimensioned usefully in most cases.

Many (possibly most) power supplies do not tolerate reverse current flow well unless  specifically designed to tolerate it or to prevent it.
When your ground fuse blows to have a potential path from +12V through the 12Vand 3.3V loads INTO the 3.3V supply. The supply sees a reverse voltage of (12-3.3) = 8.7V. This may destroy the 3.3V regulator, and/or the current may flow around or through the regulator into the input of the 3V3 supply. This may "pump up" the input voltage and cause more damage.
The same applies to the 5V supply.

Also - to be useful a common fuse must be able to tolerate normal acceptable currents but blow on overload. As an example only, imagine that you have supplies rated at 12V, 1A, 5V 10A, 3.3V 2A.
The total normal operating current MAY be as high as 1 + 10 + 2 = 13A.
A say 15A fuse may be appropriate to allow normal operation.
But if the 5V current is say 2A and the 3V3 current is 1A then the 12V current can be 15-2-1 = 12A before the fuse reaches rate current - so I_12V is 12/1 = 12 times above rated value, and the fuse will not usually blow. A fast blow fuse usually blows rapidly at around 2 x its rated current so in this case you'd need about 27A to rapidly blow the fuse.
If the fault is to ground it's resistance is ~= R = V/I = 12/27 ~= 0.5 Ohm, so the 12V load would be about 0.5 Ohms.
R_5V ~= R = 5V/2A = 2.5 Ohm,  so
The 12V supply attempts to inject i = V/R = (12-5)/(2.5 + 0.5) = ~= 2.5A into the 5V supply. This may desctroy the 5V regulator - and/or the 5V caps, depending where the fuse is in the "ground" lead.
If the 5V regulator has a reverse polarity connected "protection" diode the 12V supply will instead inject current into the 5V regulator input circuitry,. And ... .

Loads may be dynamic and may draw less current when exposed to reverse bias.
Or, they may draw more.

ie

No!